# (MYSQL) Why is the child row not being updated if the FK has ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables

**1. PARTNERS**

[image: partners table]

```
CREATE TABLE `PARTNERS` (
  `balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `lead_source` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `default_profile` int DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`lead_source`),
  KEY `PROFILE_EXISTS_idx` (`default_profile`),
  KEY `LEAD_SOURCE_VALID_idx` (`lead_source`),
  CONSTRAINT `PROFILE_EXISTS` FOREIGN KEY (`default_profile`) 
  REFERENCES `PARTNERS_PROFILES` (`id_profile`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**2. TREE**

[image: tree table]

```
CREATE TABLE `PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE` (
  `lead_source` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `master` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lead_source`),
  KEY `SUB_LEAD_SOURCE_EXISTS_idx` (`master`),
  
  CONSTRAINT `LEAD_SOURCE_EXISTS` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_source`) 
  REFERENCES `PARTNERS` (`lead_source`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  
  CONSTRAINT `MASTER_EXISTS` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_source`) 
  REFERENCES `PARTNERS` (`lead_source`) ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

as you can see the table `PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE` has **2 FK**, both with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

But when I try doing:
`` UPDATE `CRM`.`PARTNERS` SET `lead_source` = 'LAT01TEST' WHERE (`lead_source` ='LAT01'); ``

I receive the error:

```
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CRM`.`PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE`, CONSTRAINT `MASTER_EXISTS` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_source`) REFERENCES `PARTNERS` (`lead_source`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `CRM`.`PARTNERS` SET `lead_source` = 'LAT01TEST' WHERE (`lead_source` = 'LAT01')
```

I am not sure why, if it suppose to also update in the referenced table.

*(and yes I know generally this is a design problem but we need it to be this way)*

Deleting one of the FK only updates 1 row, i need BOTH of them to be updated

[image: error]

Comment: It might be useful to make the 2 columns caslled `lead_source` the same size!

Comment: You have 2 constraints in ...TREE that do almost the same thing, try removing `CONSTRAINT \`MASTER_EXISTS\` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_source`) 
  REFERENCES \`PARTNERS\` (`lead_source`) ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: I need it to be this way tho, its a tree representation of nodes, who is parent of who, if the parent is updated, it must be updated in both columns and in both columns needs to check the integrity, both columns are different and both have different meaning

Comment: YES!!!! BUT !!!!! The **TWO** Constraints do the same thing!!! Only One does `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` and the other JUST `ON UPDATE CASCADE` I would guess they are getting in each others way

Comment: Yes, I tested and if you drop either FK constraint, so there's only one handling the ON UPDATE logic, then the UPDATE of the parent table works fine.

Comment: I'll try then, but only one will be updated, i need both to be.

Comment: Tried, only one row got updated, this is not what we need, we need both of them

Comment: check the last pic in the question post

Answer (score 0):

Okay given the latest example in your question, it's more clear what you want. You need to make a different foreign key so the `master` column is also a reference to the `PARTNERS` table.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE` 
       DROP CONSTRAINT `MASTER_EXISTS`;
    
mysql> ALTER TABLE `PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE`
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (`master`) REFERENCES `PARTNERS` (`lead_source`) 
       ON UPDATE CASCADE;

mysql> UPDATE `PARTNERS` SET `lead_source` = 'LAT01TEST' 
       WHERE (`lead_source` ='LAT01');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE`;
+-------------+-----------+
| lead_source | master    |
+-------------+-----------+
| LAT01TEST   | NULL      |
| LAT01_01_01 | LAT01TEST |
| LAT01_02    | LAT01TEST |
| LAT01_03    | LAT01TEST |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: so youre basically saying i need to drop the constraint and add a FK, because i supposedly did with: ```CONSTRAINT `MASTER_EXISTS` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_source`) REFERENCES `PARTNERS` (`lead_source`) ON UPDATE CASCADE``` in the second table creation

Comment: The `master` column must be the subject of one foreign foreign key. You are declaring two foreign keys, both for the `lead_source` column.

Comment: But so you did in : ```ALTER TABLE `PARTNERS_LEAD_SOURCE_TREE`
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (`master`) REFERENCES `PARTNERS` (`lead_source`) 
       ON UPDATE CASCADE;``` ‍♂️ that would be a second FK

Comment: And it works that way, as I demonstrated. What I posted in my answer above was a copy & paste from a test that worked, I didn't just make it up. The foreign key is on a different column, that is, `master`.